# pod trying to attach disk in different zone than vm node on AKS kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

After managed aks  upgrade, my pod can't attach azure disk (I can see *ContainerCreating* status). This is because pod is being scheduled on VM node which lives in different zone than azure disk. As a workaround, I tried to edit deployment (thru azure portal) adding node selector:

```
nodeSelector:
        zone: **eastus-1**
```

But this doesn't help, pod is still scheduled on node in **eastus-2**. How do I force pod , taint node to get what I want ?

Comment: can you add a sample file  where you added `nodeSelector` ?

Comment: I've added to the deployment, actually changing zone to 
failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone fixed the issue...

Comment: Ok, glad you figured it out. Either delete the question or answer the solution so it would help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after updating deployment with the following node selector:

```
nodeSelector:
  failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone: eastus-1
```

It makes sure that the disk attached to pod is in the same zone as node